# Intellij setting code columns with shortcut key

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there some way in IntelliJ to define a shortcut key to auto-indent key - value pairs?

Instead of this:

```
  form {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
```

I very much prefer this:

```
  form {
    position:       relative;
    display:        table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    outline:        0;
    border-radius:  4px;
  }
```

Note:
I'm quite peculiar about the formatting of my personal code (hobby project) and spend a good amount making it as readable as possible. I'm also a bit concerned someone may one day screw it up through a linter and auto-formatting during git commit.
If you have an alternate way of achieving this, I'd like to hear.
I apply the same formatting in JSX key-value pairs.
If not, I may have to write something myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you. For example if you are using .css file you should go:
setting -> Code style ->  Style Sheet and choose Align valued option. **(for you formatting it is Align value: On Values)**
After applying your changes you could format your code with default format short cut: Command +alt + L for Mac and for widows ctrl + alt + l

[image]

I hope it is useful :)

Comment: I'm using SCSS, but I will try this thanks. I'm also looking for a generic solution for JSX within Javascript files (it would be similar for XML attributes), do you happen to know if this is possible?

Comment: Yes, sure. Scss files will be formatted the same way with the same settings. If I am getting it right you should play with the style sheet tweaks and create your own style.xml. In this case you will be able to apply you style and make other people use it with target project.

Comment: Do you want to apply the same style for JSX and for Javascript ?

Comment: Javascript doesn't need it, but JSX can have attributes on its tags, so I wish to style them likewise as well. I will learn a bit more about how to create your own stylesheet settings, many thanks.